# Xpages Extension Library - pageTreeNode or basicLeafNode

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

With a pageTreeNode I can forward the user to another page in my application, but I cannot take any action beside this.

If I want to do some more actions, I have to use a basicLeafNode and in the action I use (for example):

viewStateBean.restoreState = true;
context.redirectToPage( "someXPage.xsp" );

Is the behavior really the same, or what is recommended to use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

following explanation I found on http://michelles-universe.blogspot.de/
hope that helps you

xe:basicLeafNode -- Use this to link to any standard URL. You can hard-code or compute the href and label properties. This can be used for links to standard Domino forms or pages, or any other general type of link. For links to another xPage, use the pageTreeNode instead

xe:pageTreeNode -- use this if you want to point to another xPage. All you need to enter is the page name in its simplest form (e.g. demo.xsp) and the text you want displayed. There is no need to compute the entire URL - that's all done for you